# How to select directed and undirected links that contain a specific record reference

Tags: sql, firebird

There are two tables: `M_LINK` and `M_LINK_DATA`.

```
CREATE TABLE M_LINK (
    ID             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ISDIRECTED     SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL CHECK (ISDIRECTED IN (0,1))
);

CREATE TABLE M_LINK_DATA (
    ID           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    LINKREF      INTEGER NOT NULL,            -- reference to any record of table M_LINK
    MAINRECREF   INTEGER DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL, -- reference to any record of some third table
    SUBRECREF    INTEGER DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL  -- reference to any record of some third table
);
```

I want to select all `SUBRECREF` of `M_LINK_DATA` where `LINKREF` is a specific record `:linkref` of `M_LINK` and `MAINRECREF` is a specific record `:recref` of some third table. So far, so good.

This is my SQL statement to do this:

```
select SUBRECREF
  from m_link_data
  where LINKREF = :linkref and
        MAINRECREF = :recref
```

Furthermore, if `ISDIRECTED` of record `:linkref` from `M_LINK` equals `0`, the result should also contain every `MAINRECREF` of `M_LINK_DATA` where `SUBRECREF` is the same specific record `:recref` of known third table.

**sample data**

```
-----M_LINK----
ID | ISDIRECTED
---+-----------
 1 |          1
 2 |          0

-------------M_LINK_DATA-------------
ID | LINKREF | MAINRECREF | SUBRECREF
---+---------+------------+----------
 3 |       1 |         10 |        11
 4 |       1 |         10 |        12
 5 |       1 |         13 |        10
 6 |       2 |         10 |        11
 7 |       2 |         14 |        11
 8 |       2 |         13 |        10
 9 |       2 |         15 |        10
```

**desired output**

for `:linkref = 1` and `:recref = 10`:

```
RECREF
------
    11
    12
```

for `:linkref = 2` and `:recref = 10`:

```
RECREF
------
    11
    13
    15
```

As you can see, there should be only one result column, containing either `MAINRECREF` or `SUBRECREF`.

Please help me extending my SQL query to consider `M_LINK.ISDIRECTED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single query without resorting to stored procedures by using a union between a query for the main direction and one for the reverse direction.

```
with directed_links as (
    select ld.linkref, ld.mainrecref as origin, ld.subrecref as target
    from m_link_data ld
    union all
    select ld.linkref, ld.subrecref as origin, ld.mainrecref as target
    from m_link_data ld
    inner join m_link l on l.id = ld.linkref
    where l.isdirected = 0
)
select target
from directed_links
where linkref = :linkref and origin = :recref
```

Comment: @ReneHoffmann I rejected your edit. I used `UNION ALL` here intentionally. Duplicates usually should not be removed as the fact that two points are doubly connected is relevant in most graphs, and `UNION DISTINCT` will have the side effect of Firebird sorting the result to detect duplicates which is inefficient if it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but this procedure returns the desired result:

```
create or alter procedure NEW_PROCEDURE_2 (
    LINKREF integer,
    RECREF integer)
returns (
    O_SUBRECREF integer)
as
declare variable V_MAINRECREF integer;
BEGIN
  FOR
    select 
        t.subrecref,t.mainrecref
    from m_link_data t
    where 
       (
          (linkref = :linkref)
       and 
          (mainrecref = :recref)

       or
      (
      (linkref = :linkref)
      and
      ((select t1.isdirected from m_link t1 where (t1.ID = :linkref)) = 0)
      and 
      (t.SUBRECREF = :recref)
      )

       )
    INTO :o_subrecref,
         :v_mainrecref
  DO
  BEGIN
    if (:o_subrecref = :recref) then  o_subrecref = :v_mainrecref;
    SUSPEND;
  END
END
```